# Developing custom Google maps search?

Tags: google-maps

I am developing a web application in which i  want  to search like swimming pool and sports club which are not in [Types supported in place search and addition](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) then what should i do to develop such kind of application ?

Comment: are you looking then at saving locations in your own database for reference, almost like a store locator script? you can then have users search by radius, category (swimming pool, sports club), etc.

Comment: No i just want search them and display on the map with their information.

Comment: if a business isn't listed as a swimming pool then how do you solve that issue? you must have a way of storing its information in a database to then display on a map.

Comment: i want to show results on map only like we search for restaurants on map and it just display results with red tag in the same way i want to display my search for swimming pool nearby and display them on map.